# Why is my node.js server process cloned?

Tags: node.js, process, server, forever

Why is my node.js server process cloned? And I did no requests since I put it up. I'm using forever node module. Could it be related?

[image]

Comment: Does it continue doing this the longer it runs? 
or does it stop at a certain number of threads/"clones"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing are the *threads* in the same node process. v8 (for optimizing functions, collecting garbage, etc.) and libuv/node (for performing file system operations on most platforms, DNS lookups, zlib, etc.) use additional threads, so those are what you are seeing.

As of this writing, v8 uses at most 4 threads (although [an option to configure this previously hardcoded value](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/03e07d32ace26259abdea059bd3b263cef3c55eb) is available in node v5.10.0+). Also, libuv by default creates a thread pool of 4 threads, but this number can be changed by setting the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` environment variable. Care should be taken when adjusting these values since it could affect performance negatively if set too low or set too high.

FWIW in htop's setup menu you can configure it (under display settings) to both show process trees and make threads a different color. Those changes will make it easier to see the difference between threads and processes.

Comment: What does that mean? Why do I need more threads? When I start the server I have only 2 threads but they are cloned over time and memory usage increases. I don't want memory usage to increase like this.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more detail. There is no increased memory usage as they are *not separate processes*. The only way to reduce memory usage for *threads* themselves would be to reduce the OS stack size and other such resource limits.